# Date.newInstance() bug?

Tags: apex, date

I was having issues with a method that was repeatedly printing out wrong dates, when I executed this in anonymous apex

```
Date foo = date.newinstance(2016, 27, 7);//year, month, day
system.debug(foo);
```

This is what was output:

> 19:02:05:002 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|2018-03-07 00:00:00

Has anyone else encountered this or know of a work around?

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: there is no month 27 so it adds the remaining months to it i believe

Comment: @Eric, that was it - I feel so silly now! I had even made a comment for myself to avoid doing that

Comment: No problem. Not sure about the adding of months but I think thats what it is doing. 27-4 = 23, add 23 months get 3-2018

Comment: @Eric JavaScript does the same thing. I think it's to make it easier to find arbitrary dates (like you could add 60 months to find the end date).

Comment: @sfdcfox - so it must be from Jan? cause from april it would be 7-2018

Comment: @Eric Yeah, the year sets the date to Jan 1, XXXX (whatever), then the second param calls addMonths, and the third param calls addDays. I think. It's not documented, but it's not strictly a bug.

Comment: Actually... this is interesting. I think I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Date.newInstance actually seems to behave as follows:

```
public class Date {
    public static Date newInstance(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day) {
        Date d = new Date(1, 1, 1);
        d.addYears(year-1);
        d.addMonths(month-1);
        d.addDays(day-1);
        return d;
    }
}
```

Curiously, year cannot be negative, so it has the net effect of wrapping upwards:

```
Date.newInstance(-3, 1, 1);
// 0004-01-01
```

The system represents the date as a number of milliseconds, so if you exceed the maximum value, your Date will debug oddly:

```
Date.newInstance(1000000000, 1, 1);
// 169104628-12-10 19:08:16
```

---

This allows you to do things like...

## Last Day of Previous Year

```
Date.newInstance(year, 1, 0);
```

## Last Day of Previous Month

```
Date.newInstance(year, month, 0);
```

## Determine End Date of 60-Month Contract:

```
Date.newInstance(startYear, startMonth+60, 0);
```

Comment: lol - Jynx - much better than mine